# Get previous page count if text goes more than 2 characters

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am building a **load more** functionality in `v-autocomplete` (`vuetify's` component).

Here is my logic:

-1: Register `keyup` event function and, **if the text goes more than 2 characters, it will call `fetch`**, here's the code:

```
// Data
Search = '';
CurrentPage = 1;
Timer;

// Search
search(event) {
  const value = event.target.value;
  if (!!value && value.length > 2) {
    if (this.Timer) {
      clearTimeout(this.Timer);
    }
    this.Timer = setTimeout(() => {
      this.fetch(false);
    }, 500);
  }
```

-2: Here the `fetch` function which will call the API:

```
fetch(IsLoadMore) {
  if (IsLoadMore) {
    this.CurrentPage++;
    API.get(this.Search, this.CurrentPage);
  } else if (!!this.Search && this.Search.length > 2) {
    this.CurrentPage = 1;
    API.get(this.Search, this.CurrentPage);
  }
}
```

-3: And here's the component:

```
<v-autocomplete
  :search-input.sync="Search"
  cache-items
  @keyup="search"
>
  <template v-slot:append-item>
    <v-btn
      small
      class="pa-0"
      block
      color="success"
      @click="fetch(true)" <!-- Load More -->
    >Load More</v-btn>
</v-autocomplete>
```

Now, I am having some problem here, let's understand it by some sample inputs:

1. Action => *Page Load*, `CurrentPage = 1, Search = ''`

Data comes with page 1 from API.

2. Action => *Load More*, `CurrentPage = 2, Search = ''`

Data comes with page 2 from API.

3. Action => *Load More*, `CurrentPage = 3, Search = ''`

Data comes with page 3 from API.

4. Action => *Load More*, `CurrentPage = 4, Search = ''`

Data comes with page 4 from API.

5. Action => *Keyup*, `CurrentPage = 4, Search = 'Vu'` <= *Vu* length is `< 2`

so, Data remains the same

6. Action => *Keyup*, `CurrentPage = 1, Search = 'Vue'` <= *Vue* length is `> 2`

so, Data comes with page 1 and query *Vue* from API.

7. Action => *Keyup*, `CurrentPage = 1, Search = ''`

Nothing happens as search reseted (*text < 2*), but notice `CurrentPage = 1`

8. Action => *Load More*, `CurrentPage = 2, Search = ''`

Data comes with page 2 from API, **here's the problem begins**, because I am using `cache-items` *(which actually caches the data)* I don't need to fetch page 2 data again, I need to fetch the page number 5 data as **I have data till page 4**

I need to take a note of the last page with `Search < 3`, I have tried some solutions but not working, one of those solution is to make `PreviousPage = -1`, and if `Search === 3`, set `PreviousPage = CurrentPage`, but it doesn't work, and load more accordingly.

Any Suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
fetch(IsLoadMore) {
  if (IsLoadMore) {
    this.CurrentPage++;
    API.get(this.Search, this.CurrentPage);
  } else if (!!this.Search && this.Search.length > 2) {
    if (this.CurrentPage > 1) // <-- here's the trick!
      this.PreviousPage = this.CurrentPage;
    this.CurrentPage = 1;
    API.get(this.Search, this.CurrentPage);
  }
}
```

Make sure you make `PreviousPage` variable and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your response, let me try it!

Comment: Oh! really thanks man! You made my day, can't explain it. There are some issues but I will figure that out, I was in need of key thing which you answered, again really really thanks man!

Comment: Glad i helped you! let me know i you need any other help regarding this!